# How to check If entry exist in Table? MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am designing something similar to facebook groups. I have **user** table and **Community** with one relationship table name **CommunityUser**. I want to know if the user already joined a community or not? This can take if the communityID exist against that userID in CommunityUser Table. 
Here is my IsMember() function code.

```
public bool IsMember(string UserID, int CommunityID)
    {
        var MembershipUser = db.Users.Include(x => x.CommunityUsers).Where(s => s.Id == UserID).FirstOrDefault();

        var Membership = MembershipUser.CommunityUsers.Count();
        if (Membership > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
     }
```

I have virtual connection in my User Table

```
public virtual ICollection<CommunityUser> CommunityUsers { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        CommunityUsers = new Collection<CommunityUser>();
    }
```

Comment: In what way is the code not working as expected?  You're talking about Entity Framework, what does this have to do with ASP.NET MVC?  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: You have some code that appears to do what you described is your goal. What's wrong? How is this code not performing as you described?

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on returning a boolean value, just consider using the `Any()` method:

```
public bool IsMember(string UserID, int CommunityID)
{
    // This will return if a given user exists
    return db.Users.Any(u => u.Id == UserId);
}
```

Likewise, you could also consider pulling in the related CommunityUsers collection and checking that within your query as well:

```
public bool IsMember(string UserID, int CommunityID)
{
    // This will return true if a given user exists and if a specific
    // CommunityId is present for that user
    return db.Users.Include("CommunityUsers")
                   .Any(u => u.Id == UserId && u.CommunityUsers.Any(c => c.Id == CommunityId));
}
```